# Adding Bootstrap With @material-ui?

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, material-ui, bootstrap-5

Is there is anyway I can pass any bootstrap class to @material-ui ?
for small example :
here I'm trying to create a button and style it with css and bootstrap classed using both 'btn' and 'btn-primary' .

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    btn: {
        class : 'btn btn-primary', 
        padding : '2rem' , 
    },
}));



export default useStyles;
```

Please Anyone with help

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use only 1 css framework so you don't get confused during maintance, if to make it like this

```
 btn: {
     class : 'btn btn-primary',
     padding : '2rem' ,
 },
```

the material ui already exists, just customize it yourself

Comment: Thanks , didn't work tho :(

Comment: using 2 frameworks is a bit difficult to use, it's better to use custom css if the desired style is not in the framework